# Play 2.3.7 WS Client

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am using Play 2.3.7. I am using the WS client to make REST calls. I have two questions

1. I am setting the cookies on my request like

   ```
   ws.url.withHeaders("Cookie", "cookie_name=foo")
   ```

I also want to set maxAge, domain, path, secure and httponly attributes of the cookie. Any idea of how to do this without vanilla string concat. is there an API way?

2. I have to do a POST with Json Content. I see that the WSClient API needs either a FILE or an Object which is serializable to json. In my case my content is already json string. so all i need to do is to post the string. (which is already json).

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't believe there's an API for this. You'll have to build the string yourself.
2. Yes, just POST the JSON string and set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

   ```
   ws.url(url)
     .addHttpHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json")
     .post(jsonString)
   ```

   See: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWS#Request-with-additional-headers

Comment: My question was about cookies and all the attributes of cookies. not the headers. (although cookie is a header. I still need the full string.

Comment: The answer to your question about cookies ("Any idea of how to do this without vanilla string concat. is there an API way?") is that there is no API for it and that you'll have to do a vanilla string concat yourself. Sorry. :)